# Changing Access table names with VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a few tables that I import using a macro and then run some SQL queries, currently I have to rename the files before I import them and would like to automatically change their names after import.

For example I have a file called `SSIReport()` and would like to change this table to `SSI_Data`. One issue is that within the brackets of SSIReport is a date of when the file is generated so it changes.
Here is a little bit of code I currently use to delete import error tables, I am unsure if there is a way to convert this into rename tables.

```
For Each otable In CurrentDb.TableDefs
If otable.Name Like "*ImportErrors*" Then
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete otable.Name
End If
Next otable
```

Comment: I tried a DoCmd.Rename though with changing file names I was not sure how to include a LIKE into that. I also have a loop that deleted import error tables.

Comment: Have a table, say tblMatrix, then you can have the part word, so say SSI and then the table name, so SSI_Data, then you can check the file name in this table and return, using docmd.transferspreadsheet.  Not in access at mo, so not 100% sure, this is probably where I'd start https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx

Comment: `DoCmd.Rename strNewName, acTable, strOldName` works. I'm not sure what the actual problem is you have.

Comment: If strOldName changes every week when I import a file with dates in it

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the job.

```
Dim dbCurr As DAO.Database
Dim tdfCurr As DAO.TableDef

Set dbCurr = CurrentDb()
For Each tdfCurr In dbCurr.TableDefs
If Left$(tdfCurr.Name, 4) = "dbo_" Then
tdfCurr.Name = Mid$(tdfCurr.Name, 5)
End If
Next tdfCurr
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to rename the files before you import them.

Comment: So there is no fairly simple way to go about this then?

Comment: Not with a macro, I think, but I don't do macros.

Comment: When you say macro that includes the VBA coding aspect correct?

Comment: No, macros and VBA are two different things. But I can see that @Andre already provided the method for renaming a table.